# Setting id dynamically in jade / id interpolation

Tags: node.js, pug

I've tried all the permutations I can think of but alas with no success.
I am trying to set an id dynamically in a jade template.

```
#{page.name}(data-role= 'page', data-theme= 'c', data-url='#{"#"+page.name}')
```

I wondering if it's actually possible.
Anyone know how to do this?

If some one knows, please help me out - before all my hair falls out :(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer to this:
Answered kindly by TJ the developer of express.

> div(id=myPassedId),
>
> div##{myPassedID}( isn't supported because it would be super ugly

Comment: TJ is also the developer of Jade :P

Comment: lets say i want to have a concatenated id like `id="element_#{passedID}"`

Comment: it worked for me `li.album(id='album_'+album._id, rel=album._id)`

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions here did not work in my scenario...

The format that worked for me:

```
x-task-id!="<%= id %>"
```

Ugly, but functional.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can also use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
- const page = { name: 'foo' }
#{page.name}(data-role="page" data-theme="c" data-url=`#${page.name}`)
```

Output (using Pug 2.0.4):

```html
<foo data-role="page" data-theme="c" data-url="#foo"></foo>
```